# How to get all the Falsy variables without using `if` statements

Tags: python

Let's say I have multiple variables like:

```
x = 0
y = 2

if x and y:
   pass
```

How can I determine which of the variables are **not `True`**? I am trying to identify this without using the `if` statements. For the above example, I want to just get `0` (*falsy* value) skipping the `2` (*truthy* value).

Comment: What's your problem with using another `if`.

Comment: what do mean by these variable aren't `True`? Do you want to check whether they hold boolean `False` or any falsy value like `0`, `''`, `False`, `[]`, etc?

Comment: I just want to know if there is maybe another way
Lets say I have more than two variables.
I dont want to write x if statements

Comment: @Anonymous I want to check which of these variables returns False 
U can replace it whith if x and y ==  5
Idc about if its empty or not I just want to know which of these is False - the variables are just an example :)

Comment: **I dont want to write x if statements** then write one by using a list instead of individual variables and loop over them.

Comment: @Countour-Integral That would be one way - thanks.
But is it possible without a loop?

Comment: @DeF3c What are you trying to do exactly? This seems like an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. Why wouldn't you want to use a loop?

Comment: Updated the question based on the clarifications from you on my answer to make it easier for future readers. Feel free to edit it back in case I incorrectly changed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `tuple` of all your variables. And then use [`itertools.filterfalse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) with [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) as *predicate* value to get all the *Falsy* values from tuple as:

```
>>> from itertools import filterfalse
>>> my_list = (1, "a", False, 2.34, "", 0)

>>> list(filterfalse(bool, my_list))
[False, '', 0]
```

Similarly if you need a list of all the *Truthy* values, you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) as:

```
>>> my_list = (1, "a", False, 2.34, "", 0)

>>> list(filter(bool, my_list))
[1, 'a', 2.34]
```

Comment: Yessss thats it  itertools.filterfalse()
Thats what I need -  I love your - Cheers